# Change the Width and Height on UserControl at runtime

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I need to figure out how to change the `UserControl's` `Width` and `Height` at runtime. I am trying to do this during a `mouseMove` event. The `Width` and `Height` are set to `Auto` in `XAML`.

```
'mouseDown event
mouseVerticalPosition = e.GetPosition(Nothing).Y
mouseHorizontalPosition = e.GetPosition(Nothing).X

'mouseMove event
Dim deltaV As Double = e.GetPosition(Nothing).Y - mouseVerticalPosition
Dim deltaH As Double = e.GetPosition(Nothing).X - mouseHorizontalPosition

Me.Width = Me.Width + deltaH
UpdateLayout() 'does not work
```

This code is inside of the `UserControl` not the `Page` where the `UserControl` lives - if that helps.

Consider the container and it's properties - auto and stretch are used here:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
 <Canvas Name="cnv" Margin="18">
      <Rectangle Name="Rect" Margin="0" />
 </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual numeric value of an `Auto` setting on `Width` or `Height` is `Double.NaN`. When you add anything to that initial NaN value the result will always still be NaN. You can either use `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` instead as the number to add to or try adding a `Double.IsNaN` check before you set the value and if true just use `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`.

Comment: Those are `ReadOnly` properties so I guess I am not understanding how to use them. I even tried to start with fixed sized to avoid the NaN thing.

Comment: I found that if I set all three(UC, Grid, Canvas) to a size it does change the Width, but I need the Grid and the Canvas to resize(stretch) to the UC - which does not happen if they are set to Auto and the UC is set to a size intially. Very confusing!

Comment: Width = ActualWidth + deltaH

Comment: When I try that It does change, the Canvas is still staying the same size - even with Auto and Stretch properties - hmm...

Comment: How are you looking at the size of the Canvas? It can be difficult to tell in the UI since Canvas is essentially just an infinite space that is clipped and its child elements often stay in a fixed position relative to the outer container, unlike a * sized Grid for example.

Comment: I did a background color and yes it is growing. I must be missing setting some other properties while resizing it.

Comment: You did answer my question so I will award and come back with a diff question. Thanks for the help.